# What are the benefits of using TLS Client-Side?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

I have a couple questions.

If I were to use TLS1.0->1.3 Client-Side and never use SSLv2 or v3, would there be any impacts on TCP Client Handshake Compatibility?

As in, would there ever be a server that wouldn't support this change that would require me to use SSLv2/v3?

I guess what i'm asking is if TLS is backwards compatible which servers that use SSLv2/v3 or do I not understand SSL/TLS properly?

Also other way around, if I was running an OS that had no support for TLS, would I at some point end up with Protocol Issues when Handshaking an SSL Stream?

Comment: There are many excellent documents covering this question on the Internet. The topic is very large and not suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: SSLv2/v3 are old and almost disabled everywhere. You will hardly find someone using them.